# Display port from GTX 1070 to mini display port on 4K Dell monitor

Tags: displayport

I have a Dell p2715q monitor that I use for a Mac Pro and a PC that I just built for 3D work. The monitor has 1 Display Port, 1 Mini Display Port, and 1 HDMI port. I'm currently using the Display Port for my Mac Pro and the HDMI for the PC. The problem is that the HDMI only supports 30Hz and I'd like to use the Mini DP because it supports 60Hz.

So I know that most people use the mini dp on laptops to go to a full size dp on monitors. I can find that type of cable but they supposedly only work that way, not in reverse.

Do you guys know of a way to go from Display Port to Mini DP on m monitor?

Comment: "but they supposedly only work that way, not in reverse." - Why do you believe this to be the case?

Answer (score 0):

Display port and mini display port is basically the same just a different size so if you
just search for "display port to mini display port adapter" you can buy an adapter or adapting cable for a few bucks

Answer (score 0):

Its actually one of the 'default' ways the P2715Q's supposed to be connected, and it ought to be covered in the manual. You can connect video card side DP to monitor side mini DP. Mini DP and DP are *electrically* compatible/identical and the cable works 'both' ways

I use it that way from a 980Ti to the monitor with the cable that comes with the monitor and it works fine. Just make sure you're not using a passthrough port.